# Schema Microdata Product Description Markup

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

I have a question regarding the markup of product descriptions using the Schema.org microdata standard.

I've seen in the documentation that a products' description is marked-up as:

```
<span itemprop="description">Some kind of product description.</span>
```

However I was wondering how I'd correctly markup a product page who's description was spread across multiple tags. Do I always have to use the `<span>` tag? Does a the `itemprop="description"` part need to applied directly to the texts parent tag, or can I merely wrap the whole section?

Take, for example, part of a product page for an item of clothing. How would I mark this up?

```
<div class="productCopy">
  <p>Exclusive to us [brand name]. Three-quarter sleeved jersey dress in a burnout print devore fabric, with scoop neckline. Gather detail to side waist and mock wrap skirt. Fully lined.</p>
  <ul class="features">
    <li>Length 41in/104cm. Sits below knee.</li>
    <li class="ProductCopy">Hand wash.</li>
    <li class="ProductCopy">90% Polyester, 10% Elastane. Lining: Polyester.</li>
    <li>...other potential product features...</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="characteristics">
    <li>Product available in sizes: 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32 </li>
    <li>Available in: Black, Wine</li>
    <li>...other potential product characteristics...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And yes, I know the current markup isn't pretty - something I don't have the authority to change at the moment.

Thanks for any advice.

Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just wrap up. So if you want the whole text to be description of your product you can do smth like this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <div itemprop="description" class="productCopy">
    <p>Exclusive to us [brand name]. Three-quarter sleeved jersey dress in a burnout print devore fabric, with scoop neckline. Gather detail to side waist and mock wrap skirt. Fully lined.</p>
    <ul class="features">
      <li>Length 41in/104cm. Sits below knee.</li>
      <li class="ProductCopy">Hand wash.</li>
      <li class="ProductCopy">90% Polyester, 10% Elastane. Lining: Polyester.</li>
      <li>...other potential product features...</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="characteristics">
      <li>Product available in sizes: 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32 </li>
      <li>Available in: Black, Wine</li>
      <li>...other potential product characteristics...</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

which will [give](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:8004e5f96143662d9a38ea1e81b3e815) you

[image]

Or you can give more granular markup, e.g., to mark particular characteristics.

You can find out more about microdata itemprop processing [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#names:-the-itemprop-attribute) (W3C spec).